# Setting up a server with a non-local IP address in C++ (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, ip-address

I'm new to network programming, so I'm not sure this is really the right question, but I want to make a server program with C++ (I'm using Qt.)  I've used the "fortune server" example which creates a simple server which you can connect to with a client by typing in the IP address the server displays.  I can connect if I enter localhost (127.0.0.1), but the address the server says it's running on is 169.254.253.67, which I found out is another local address (and I can't connect to it, either.)  How can I run the server so it's not on a local address?

Here's the example I use:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/network-fortuneserver.html

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking however if you use 0.0.0.0 as the listen address the server will listen on all nics in your PC. Or you can specify the external ipaddress to the listen() call.

Comment: You could use the following link to figure out what the ipaddress is of the primary nic: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/1439

Comment: @drescherjm You can't specify an external IP address.

Comment: Hmm. I have the following code where m_serverIP is a QTcpServer:  m_pPrivate->m_server.listen(m_pPrivate->m_serverIP,m_pPrivate->m_nPort);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server implementation gets a list of all the discovered ip addresses, and then finds the first non-local ip. Otherwise, it defaults to using localhost. If you are seeing a local host address, then it indicates something is not set up right in your network and Qt could not determine the LAN ip.

As suggested by @drescherjm in comments, you could explicitly listen on all interfaces via `0.0.0.0`. To see this in action, you would just need to add a line right before it sets the status label with the `ipAddress` string:

```
// add this to force the socket to listen on all interfaces
ipAddress = QHostAddress("0.0.0.0").toString();
// or if you have a local static ip and want to be explicit
// ipAddress = QHostAddress("192.168.xxx.xxx").toString();

// followed by the already existing line for setting the text
statusLabel->setText(tr("The server is running on\n\nIP: %1\nport: %2\n\n"
                        "Run the Fortune Client example now.")
                     .arg(ipAddress).arg(tcpServer->serverPort()));
```

Now if your network is set up correctly, any other computer that can see the one running the server app should be able to connect on the given port.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I did more research, and found out the problem is that I'm connected to a router, so I'm given a local IP address (192.168.1.x as you said), and I can't create a server with that IP that can be connected to globally.  I guess I need to set up port forwarding or something?

Comment: Oh, to have WAN clients connect through your router? Yes you would need to set up port forwarding on the router so that it sends traffic on your specific TCP port to your local address. Then outside clients would connect to your public IP on that port and get routed to your local machine.